How do I pass the value of a store as a prop in Svelte, where the store is an object member?
Suppose I have a list of items with Svelte stores as members, e.g.:
interface Item {
  isAvailable: Writable<boolean>;
}

If I have some component with a boolean prop, how do I pass values from those stores to that prop if I'm iterating over the items?
I would have thought there'd be some straightforward syntax resembling this:
{#each items as item}
  <Component isEnabled={item.$isAvailable} />
{/each}

The best solution I can think of would be defining another component something like:
<script>
  export let item: Item;

  $: isAvailable = item.isAvailable;
</script>

<Component isEnabled={$isAvailable} />

But that seems like an excessive amount of boilerplate.

Looks like the boilerplate cannot be avoided (source) but this may be fixed in Svelte 5 (source).
I have found a partial solution to this issue which at least avoids having to make multiple components... by creating a utility function like this:
export function toReadable<T>(value: T | Readable<T>): Readable<T> {
    if (value instanceof Object) {
        return value;
    } else {
        return readable(value);
    }
}

and updating the prop in Component (assuming it's yours) to this:
export let isEnabled: boolean | Readable<boolean> = false;

$: isEnabledStore = toReadable(isEnabled);

you can basically allow either a value or a store to be passed which then supports what I want:
{#each items as item}
  <Component isEnabled={item.isAvailable} />
{/each}

Solution seems to be working... I'll update this answer if I find any drawbacks.

You can do this as follows.
Create a store file like so.
import { writable } from 'svelte/store';

interface Item {
    isAvailable: boolean;
}

export const ItemStore = writable<Item | undefined>()

In svelte file,
<script>
    // TODO: import ItemStore.
    import { get } from 'svelte/store';
    
    const item = get(ItemStore);
    
    console.log(item.isAvailable);
</script>

The get method from svelte/store will subscribe to the store, gets the value and unsubscrbe from it.
